# Declare final fun in interface

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I'm writing a cooperative multithreading engine in Kotlin. I'm trying to write an interface as follows:

```
interface Processor {
    var suspendAction: (Continuation<Any>) -> Unit

    inline suspend fun yield() = suspendCoroutine(suspendAction)

    suspend fun process(inbox: Inbox) = Unit
}
```

`yield()` is a service I want to provide to all implementors of this interface. Since each virtual call site represents a barrier to inlining, and since each entry point into a `suspend fun` has its cost, for performance reasons I need this function to be `final`, but Kotlin doesn't allow me that. I found a workaround in turning `yield()` into an extension fun:

```
inline suspend fun Processor.yield() = suspendCoroutine(suspendAction)
```

I'd like to ask whether use cases as this might motivate the Kotlin language designers to allow `final fun` in `interface`.

Note that, unlike in the typical wait-for-IO suspension scenarios, here `yield()` occurs on a hot, CPU-intensive thread.

Comment: You can make `yield` a top-level function (which is compiled as `static final`) and refer to it in Javadoc (Kdoc)..

Comment: Extension function `yield` is not a workaround for your use-case. It is exactly how "final fun in interface" are supposed to be represented in Kotlin by design.

Comment: @RomanElizarov I thought about it after writing this question and I agree. My initial worry was that a Java static method receiving the processor's `this` as argument is not on the same footing as a member method receiving it, regarding allowable compiler optimizations. After more consideration i think it actually is on the same footing.

Comment: ... because it is an `inline` function so it's not actually compiled as a Java static method, but exactly the same as if its code was a part of another member function. It is often easier to think about `inline` functions as macros.